# chroot not able to start service - not found. What is missing?

Tags: chroot, netbsd

I would like to run a service inside a chroot in a NetBSD 9.1 amd64 system.
The service runs if invoked from OS.
The service in question is `dendrite-monolith-server`.  I just copied the file for ease of use to `start` sitting inside the chroot in `/bin/`.

```
# ldd bin/start 
bin/start:
        -lpthread.1 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.1
        -lc.12 => /usr/lib/libc.so.12
```

They are hard linked:

```
# ls -l usr/lib
total 8560
-r--r--r--  2 root  pe  2079984 Feb 22 23:40 lc.12
-r--r--r--  2 root  pe  2079984 Feb 22 23:40 libc.so.12
-r--r--r--  2 root  pe    93656 Feb 22 23:40 libpthread.so.1
-r--r--r--  2 root  pe    93656 Feb 22 23:40 lpthread.1
```

In the chroot `/dev`, did `MAKEDEV all` to create the devices.

Copied `ld.elf_so` to the chroot `/libexec` directory

```
# ls -l /libexec/
total 324
-r-xr-xr-x  1 0  1000  164344 Feb 22 23:47 ld.elf_so
```

ksh93 is statically linked:

```
# chroot ./ /bin/ksh93
#
# /bin/start 
/bin/ksh93: /bin/start: not found
```

What's wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up untarring the `base.tar.xz` package of the NetBSD installation sets to a new directory, copy the contents of the web service to there and it ran.